# How to explain this quirk of the chain rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

Assume I have a function $f = f(y, \phi(y,x))$ and I want to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, I use the chain rule to get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} 
\end{equation}

but obviously the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ represent different things on each side of equality. How do I explain this? I'm guessing it is a notational issue.

---

Edit: Just to give some context why this troubles me. Here $x_i$ refers to the ith component of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ in euclidean space. In an acoustic textbook the Lighthill stress tensor $T_{ij}$ is involved in the following identity:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},t-|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|/c)}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} = \frac{\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial y_i}}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} - \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} \frac{T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},t-|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|/c)}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}  \end{equation}

This can only be resolved if the numerator in the term $\frac{\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial y_i}}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}$ is given a different interpretation...Just try showing this:

Let $t-|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|/c = \phi(t,\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$

\begin{array}{lcl} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi)}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} & = & \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi) + T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}  \\  
& = &  \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} (\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}) + T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}\\ 
& = &  -\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} (\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y_i}) + T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} 
\end{array}

\begin{array}{lcl} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} \frac{T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi)}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} & = & \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi) + T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi) \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}  \\  
& = &  \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} ( \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}T_{ij} +\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y_i}) - T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},\phi) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} 
\end{array}

Adding up the last line from each expression gives the result.

Comment: The one on the right hand side should be interpreted as the derivative of f with respect to the first coordinate.  You are right that you just need to be more careful with notation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you show me what you mean, how would you write this? Thanks!

Comment: If you write $f_i$ for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the $i$th parameter, the chain rule becomes $\frac{\partial f(y,\phi(y,x))}{\partial y}=f_1 + f_2\phi_1$

Comment: I think you can use the notation $\frac{df}{dy}$ for the left hand side.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

Comment: You can use it, but it's wrong. It's no secret that analysts mangle notations.

Comment: @GitGud  why would it be wrong? I guess it's not really the total derivative i'm after.. How would you write it?

Comment: @Jack There is so much abuse going on, I don't even know where to start. I will think about whether I will write an answer or not.

Comment: The problem is that two different functions are both being called "$f$".  The $f$ on the left is a different function than the $f$ on the right.  We can avoid this by letting
$F(x,y) = f(y,\phi(y,x))$.

Comment: @littleO That actually makes sense, I like that interpretation.

Comment: @littleO That is exactly what I did in my answer. I specified exactly which function was being differentiated, and at what point it was being evaluated.

Comment: @GitGud If analysts rape notations then what do differential geometers do? (Not meant as defense/offense for anyone)

Comment: @Fantini I'm not even going to go there because I don't want to offend anyone. But you know where I would go...

Comment: Yes can we please stop the vulgar references? Many people are very sensitive about these things... (not to sound bossy, I'm just saying)

Comment: What I've gathered from the areas that I've encountered is that algebra has been the most crystal clear regarding notation, but the main problem with analysis/geometry is that the abuse of notation is tacit. It would go a long way to explicit the assumptions behind and, even if one time only, showed how absurd notation would be if written in full. I'm sure that'd clarify ideas for everyone.

Comment: @Fantini My answer (I think) shows the notation written in full (pretty absurd!). What do you think?

Comment: @NotNotLogical I haven't looked at it in detail yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's use a different notation: for a function of two variables $f$, denote by $\partial_1f$ and $\partial_2f$ the first-order derivatives of $f$ with respect to the first and second variable respectively, namely:
\begin{align*}
\partial_1f(x,y)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h,&
\partial_2f(x,y)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,y)-f(x,y+h)}h.
\end{align*}
Now, from the chain rule,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\Bigl(f\bigl(y,\phi(y,x)\bigr)\Bigr)
=\partial_1f\bigl(y,\phi(y,x)\bigr)+\partial_1\phi(y,x)\partial_2f\bigl(x,\phi(y,x)\bigr),$$
where
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\Bigl(f\bigl(y,\phi(y,x)\bigr)\Bigr)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\bigl(y+h,\phi(y+h,x)\bigr)-f\bigl(y,\phi(y,x)\bigr)}{h}.$$

---

In fact, I try to always be careful to what I'm writing and what I really mean. First, I'm careful to never say *the function f(x)*, but *the function $f$* (unless $f$ is a function with codomain a set of functions). At best, $f(x)$ is an *expression* that depends on $x$.

Then I use symbols like $\partial_1$, $\partial_2$, etc. for functions, and things like $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ or $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$ for expressions (though, in fact, it's slightly more complicated).

(Hence, I hate when people say something like *[something] is a function of $x$*. Heck, what does it mean to be a function of $x$? you're a function or you're not, you can't be a function of $x$; at best, you're an *expression* that depends on $x$).

---

Then there's something I like to do: take a function $f$ of two variables and define the function $g$ by
$$g(y,x)=f(x,y).$$

Then I like to ask this question: with your notation, what sense do you give to
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}?$$
or to any other variation on the theme:
$$\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x},\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y),\ \ldots$$

Comment: I appreciate the effort! I can follow your reasoning a bit. However I am a bit confused with some parts. In my edit I have written out the scenario which has led to my confusion. Would you care to look at it and offer some insight?

Comment: Also to add, im not sure why we shouldn't use the terminology "$f$ is a function of $x$". Doesn't that just mean the function takes inputs and assigns outputs, where the inputs defined for instance as $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Jack your computation seems correct (though with _funky_ notations!). The awkward part is the part you copied from the book!

Comment: @Jack Regarding _$f$ is a function of $x$_: that doesn't mean anything. A function is a box that takes an input and yields an output. That box doesn't care how you call you variables. It's just a transformation.

Comment: I don't think a total derivative (symbol) should be used here, because $x$ is independent of $y$.

Comment: @NotNotLogical I doubt it really matters here… and I don't feel like editing the post `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Fair enough :) Just wondering, you list a few ambiguous notations at the end of the post... what about $$\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}(y,x)$$ (for example), do you think that is well-defined?

Comment: @NotNotLogical, I haven't thought it out thoroughly, but your notation seems understandable and well-defined; well, let me guess: you take _the expression_ $g(x,y)$ and differentiate it wrt $x$ (this is fine, since it's an expression); then _because you wrote $(x,y)$ (with $x$ and $y$ in this order), and because you're writing $(y,x)$ in this order you mean: alright, in the expression $x$ is the first variable and $y$ is the second variable; so take the the first variable of $(y,x)$ (i.e., $y$) and put it in place of the variable in your expression, and simultaneously do the same with the 2nd.

Comment: @NotNotLogical seems alright… (yet I'm not going to use it `:D`).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ok, glad you think it makes sense. Just wanted to get another opinion!

Comment: Ah wow this is really a fantastic community! Lots of great input here. I think ill have to digest it all and tomorrow and return with an answer that combines parts from everyone.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf So about the awkward bit from the book: should the term $\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial y_i}$ just after the equals sign be interpreted differently from $\frac{\partial T_{ij}(\mathbf{y},t-|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|/c)}{\partial y_i}$ in the same way that differentiation with respect to $y$ is different as in $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$ where $F = F(y,x) = f(y, \phi(x,y))$. Please correct me if that doesnt make sense!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, Leibniz notation for partial derivatives is terrible: I avoid using it whenever possible, except for a particular usage from differential geometry. (the ambiguity you cite in your question isn't the only problem with it!)

My favorite notation is a variation of $f'$ used for the derivative of a univariate function $f$: the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the functions one would normally write as

$$ f_1(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) $$
$$ f_2(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) $$

so I would write

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(y, \phi(y,x))
= f_1(y, \phi(y,x)) + f_2(y, \phi(y,x)) \phi_1(y,x) $$

Typically, I'm interested in both partials rather than just one partial, and I would use differentials instead of partial derivatives to organize the calculation of all of them at once

$$ \mathrm{d} f(y, \phi(y,x))
= f_1(y, \phi(y,x))\, \mathrm{d}y + f_2(y, \phi(y,x)) \,\mathrm{d}\phi(y,x) = \ldots $$

and when I'm really interested in one partial, I do the same thing, except work in the setting where I've set $\mathrm{d}x=0$. (assuming the partial I really mean to use is the one where $x$ is held constant)

---

In the differential geometry setting, in my opinion there is no ambiguity:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} f(x^i, g(y^i, x^i)) $$

has only one reasonable meaning: applying the tangent vector $\partial/\partial x^i$ to the scalar field $f(x^i, g(y^i, x^i))$ in the $i$-th coordinate direction. In my opinion, you wouldn't use that notation when you wanted the derivative of $f$ with respect to its first argument.

(although this example has two sets of independent variables: which makes me again dislike using Leibniz notation for it)

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a notational ambiguity. Is is clearer to write it as $$\frac{\partial f(y,\phi(y,x))}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}(y,\phi(y,x))+\left[\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}(y,\phi(y,x))\right]\left[\frac{\partial \phi(x,y)}{\partial x}(y,x)\right]$$
In the above, the function in the numerator is the function being differentiated, and the point following the fraction is the point at which the derivative is evaluated. In other words, in $$\frac{\partial [\text{stuff}]}{\partial x}(\text{point})$$
 "stuff" is the expression which is being differentiated with respect to $x$, yielding a function. Into that function we plug the point "point" to get the answer. *E.g.*, $$\frac{\partial (x+y^3)}{\partial y}(y,x)=3y^2+0x\Bigg|_{(y,x)}=3x^2$$ Note that $$\frac{\partial h(y,x)}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial h(x,y)}{\partial x}(y,x)$$

Comment: Wait, where did the $\partial x$'s on the RHS come from?

Comment: @Sten You first differentiate $f$ with respect to its first argument, conventionally called $x$. You then plug in the appropriate point $(y,\phi(y,x))$. Same with $\phi$, where $y$ sits in the first argument, so you need to differentiate $\phi$ with respect to its first input and then plug in the point $(y,x)$.

Comment: Dear downvoters: why the downvotes?

Comment: @GitGud Consider $\phi(a,b)=a+2b$. Then $\frac{\partial \phi(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(x+2y)=2$ which is incorrect. We have $\phi(y,x)=y+2x$ so the answer should be $1$, which is what my formula produces.

Comment: @NotNotLogical $$(\partial _2\phi) (a,b)=\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\phi(a,b+h)-\phi(a,b)}{h}\right)=\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\dfrac{a+2b+2h-a-2b}{h}\right)=2,$$ therefore $\forall (u,v)\left(\partial _2(u,v)=2\right)$ or $\forall (x,y)\left(\partial _2(y,x)=2\right)$.

Comment: @GitGud I'm saying the partial with respect to $y$ of $\phi(y,x)=y+2x$ is $1$, not $2$. So $2$ is wrong.

Comment: @GitGud The partial derivative of $\phi(x,y)$ with respect to $y$ is $2$. The partial derivative of **$\phi(y,x)$** with respect to $y$ is $1$. That is the function being used in this example.

Comment: @GitGud $\phi(x,y)=x+2y$, $\phi(y,x)=y+2x$, $\phi(a,b)=a+2b$... those are functions right? I'm getting so confused now :)

Comment: I didn't downvote (and I actually just upvoted).  We could also try introducing $g(x,y) = \phi(y,x)$, and using $D_i$ notation for partial derivatives. Let $F(x,y) = f(y,g(x,y))$.  Then $D_2 F(x,y) = D_1 f(y,g(x,y)) + D_2f(y,g(x,y)) D_2 g(x,y)$.  Note that $D_2 g(x,y) = D_1 \phi (y,x)$.  So, we get $D_2 F(x,y) = D_1 f(y,\phi(y,x)) + D_2f(y,\phi(y,x)) D_1 \phi(y,x)$.

Comment: @NotNotLogical I'm confused myself because my answer agrees with yours xD

Comment: And now I would up vote the first version of your answer, but not this one because symbols like $\frac{\partial f(y,\phi(y,x))}{\partial y}(x,y)$ have no meaning. **Edit:** I've removed my comments that falsely claimed that your answer was wrong.

Comment: @GitGud I have edited, if you're not sick of reading my post :)

Answer (score -3):

It would seem you have encountered a typing error.  The left f is merely the label and the right side reveals some structure, yet it carries the same label.  So differentiating both sides eliminates the quantity sought.  This makes no sense.  What would make more sense is if the label on the left were given as g, then your computation provides an answer.  The problem is that the given equation is self-referencing and thus it leads nowhere.